# How can I detect a string based on a regex with a Squid ACL

Tags: squid

would it be possible to detect a string (a canary token, for example) with a squid proxy within a http post (or get) request? I am looking for a regex ACL on the http body, but can only find protocol fields in the ACLs

https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl